# Android - Getting data from db

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an animeList-app, like the website myAnimeList.

My problem is that the data that I show in the app from my db is "random". Some data doesn't show up or isn't right and if I click on an item (like the anime "One Piece") Toast.makeText(myAnime_completed.get(position).getName()); will give me a completely random item from the db.

I have a databaseHelper where I load data.

```
        //CREATE TABLE MYANIME
        String CREATE_TABLE_MYANIME = "CREATE TABLE myAnime (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "name TEXT," +
                "description TEXT," +
                "episodes INTEGER," +
                "genre TEXT," +
                "rating INTEGER," +
                "episodesWatched INTEGER," +
                "stateId INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MYANIME);       

private void insertMyAnime(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myAnime (name, description, episodes, genre, rating, episodesWatched, stateId) VALUES ('One Piece', 'GUUD', 700, 'brut', 0, 50, 2);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myAnime (name, description, episodes, genre, rating, episodesWatched, stateId) VALUES ('Death Note', 'GUUD TUU', 35, 'thriller', 0, 50, 1);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myAnime (name, description, episodes, genre, rating, episodesWatched, stateId) VALUES ('Fairy Tail', 'GUUD TUU', 35, 'thriller', 0, 50, 2);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myAnime (name, description, episodes, genre, rating, episodesWatched, stateId) VALUES ('Naruto', 'GUUD TUU', 35, 'thriller', 0, 50, 1);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myAnime (name, description, episodes, genre, rating, episodesWatched, stateId) VALUES ('Bleach', 'GUUD TUU', 35, 'thriller', 0, 50, 3);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myAnime (name, description, episodes, genre, rating, episodesWatched, stateId) VALUES ('No Game No Life', 'GUUD TUU', 35, 'thriller', 0, 50, 3);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myAnime (name, description, episodes, genre, rating, episodesWatched, stateId) VALUES ('Kill la Kill', 'GUUD TUU', 35, 'thriller', 0, 50, 3);");
    }
```

After this I try to seperate the data in different catagories: watching, completed, on hold, dropped and plan to watch.

```
public MyAnime getMyAnimeByID(int animeId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        MyAnime myAnime = new MyAnime();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("myAnime", new String[] { "id", "name",
                "description", "episodes", "genre", "rating",
                "episodesWatched", "stateId" }, "id = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(animeId) }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            myAnime = new MyAnime(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getInt(5), cursor.getInt(6), cursor.getInt(7));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return myAnime;
    }

    public List<MyAnime> getMyAnimes_watching() {
        List<MyAnime> myAnimeList = new ArrayList<MyAnime>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query("myAnime", 
                new String[] { "id" }, "stateId = ?", 
                new String[] { String.valueOf(1)}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                myAnimeList.add(getMyAnimeByID(cursor.getInt(0)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return myAnimeList;
    }

    public List<MyAnime> getMyAnimes_completed() {
        List<MyAnime> myAnimeList = new ArrayList<MyAnime>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("myAnime", new String[] { "id" },
                "stateId = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(2)}, null, null,
                null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                myAnimeList.add(getMyAnimeByID(cursor.getInt(0)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return myAnimeList;
    }
```

Then in the activity I get the data from the db:

```
//FILL LISTVIEW COMPLETED
    final List<MyAnime> myAnime_completed = db.getMyAnimes_completed();    
    ArrayAdapter<MyAnime> adapter_completed = new ArrayAdapter<MyAnime>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myAnime_completed);

    ListView lvCompleted = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myAnime_completed);
    lvCompleted.setAdapter(adapter_completed);

    lvCompleted.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, 
                            View childView, int position, long id) {

                    show(myAnime_completed.get(position).getName());
                    //goToNextActivity(myAnime_completed.get(position).getId());

                }
    });
```

To be honest, I'm a student and I realise that this could be very easy to solve, but for someone with not much expierience this is a braintwister.

I really hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the function show(...) shows a toast. From the information given, it looks like the code is correct and it looks like it should return OnePiece if you click the button OnePiece. However, I need more information and I can't comment. I would put a break-point at getMyAnimeByID and step through the code there to make sure it returns the right row.

I want to make sure though that the list does only show the values with stateId = 2. It also doesn't look like you need to sort it, in response to the answer below.

Here is an off-topic suggestion though:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            myAnimeList.add(getMyAnimeByID(cursor.getInt(0)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

can be reduced to

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   myAnimeList.add(...);
}
```

The cursor starts at an index of -1.

Answer (score -1):

You should be passing in a "Order By" parameter to your query when you create the cursor.  Using the db.query method you have, change the second to last null parameter to be the column you want the data sorted by.  The signature for that method is:

```
Cursor query(boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns,
        String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy,
        String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

So, you might pass in a string value of "stateId ASC".